# Поочередный вывод значений из списка

Tags: python, list

Суть проблемы:
Есть 2 списка - "**Название фильма**" и "**Год выпуска**".
Необходимо сделать так, чтобы перед названием фильма печаталось - "**Название**", а перед годом выпуска, соответственно - "**Год выпуска**"
Пример моей реализации:

```
l1 = ['Доcпехи бога', 'Доcпехи бога 2', 'Доcпехи бога 3']
l2 = ['1984', '1991', '1995']

for name in l1:
    print("Название: ")
    print(*name, sep='')
for date in l2:
    print("Год выпуска: ")
    print(*date, sep='')
```

Выводит вот это:

```
Название: 
Доcпехи бога
Название: 
Доcпехи бога 2
Название: 
Доcпехи бога 3
Год выпуска: 
1984
Год выпуска: 
1991
Год выпуска: 
1995
```

Нужно чтобы вывод был такой:

```
Название: Доспехи бога
Год выпуска: 1984
Название: Доспехи бога 2
Год выпуска: 1991
Название: Доспехи бога 3
Год выпуска: 1995
```

В google и яндекс ответ искал.
Прошу помочь)

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте так:

```
l1 = ['Доcпехи бога', 'Доcпехи бога 2', 'Доcпехи бога 3']
l2 = ['1984', '1991', '1995']

_l = zip(l1, l2)
    
for i in _l:    
    print(f"Название: {i[0]}")
    print(f"Год выпуска: {i[1]}")
```

Comment: Премного благодарен. Как я сам до этого не додумался)Теперь знаю где получать ответы на сложные вопросы)

Comment: тут можно `for name, year in _l`

Comment: @Freedom Essence да, вы не ошиблись) это супер собщество!

Answer (score 2):

Сложное лучше, чем запутанное.
Красивое лучше, чем уродливое.

```
l1 = ['Доcпехи бога', 'Доcпехи бога 2', 'Доcпехи бога 3']
l2 = ['1984', '1991', '1995']

[print(f'Название: {x[0]}\nГод выпуска: {x[1]}') for x in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот ответ. И назовите списки нормально.

```
names = ['Доcпехи бога', 'Доcпехи бога 2', 'Доcпехи бога 3']
dates = ['1984', '1991', '1995']

for name in names:
    print("Название: ",end = '')
    print(*name, sep='')
for date in dates:
    print("Год выпуска: ", end = '')
    print(*date, sep='')
```